# How do I change the transparency of an bitmap by percent in Delphi/FMX?

Tags: image, delphi, bitmap, transparency, firemonkey

For a Firemokey project i'm working on a Bitmap, which should make a Bitmap on a TImage Component to get more transparent with the time. In order to do so, i want to use a procedure like the following, but it seems as if there is no way to create a change of the transparency as the following:

```
procedure changeBitmapTransperency(TransparencyInPercent : Integer);
begin
  {Set transparency of the bitmap to (TransparencyInPercent) percent}
end;
```

So, my question is, if there is a way to do so. Thanks for your time and effort,

Max

Comment: You are looking for the [`TControl.Opacity`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.Opacity) property.  You can set the `Opacity` of the `TImage`, not the `TBitmap` itself.

Comment: @remy lebeau Does this work in firemonkey as well as in delphi? And is if in percent or just a boolean like the transparency?

Comment: Did you read the documentation I linked to?  It is in FMX only (which you said you are using anyway), and it "*takes values between 0 and 1. If `Opacity` is 1, the control is completely opaque; if it is 0, the control is completely transparent. The values over 1 are treated as 1, and the ones under 0 are treated as 0*".  You can easily calculate such a value from a percentage.

Comment: @remy lebeau Yes, i just reat it, i think this should solve my problem, thanks!